# Invalid Value with Express Validator

Tags: node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I am a bit new with Sequelize and having some issues at the moment that I can't seems to find what exactly the problem is.

Currently using express-validator to perform a custom validation if an email exist but no matter what the outcome is, it will always return an error saying Email already exist in the log but on my postman, it shows Invalid value even when it is clear that email does not exist. Below is my query

```
const { check, body, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const db = require('../app/models')
const MerchantTemp = db.rest.models.MerchantTemp

const signupValidation = () => {
    return [
        body('firstname')
            .not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('Firstname field is required'),
        body('lastname')
            .not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('Lastname field is required'),
        body('phone')
            .not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('Phone Number field is required')
            .isNumeric().withMessage('Phone Number field can only contain Numbers')
            .isLength({min: 11, max: 13}).withMessage('Phone Number field can only contain minimum of 11 and max of 13 digits respectively'),
        body('email')
            .not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('Email Address field is required')
            .isEmail().withMessage('Email field is not a valid format').normalizeEmail()
            .custom((value, { req }) => {
/**
** HAVING DIFFICULTY HERE
**/
                MerchantTemp.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } })
                    .then((result) => {
                        if (result != null){
                            throw new Error('Email address is already in use.Please try another one!');
                        }
                    }).catch(error => {
                        throw new Error(error);
                    })
            }),
        body('password')
            .not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('Password field is required')
            .isStrongPassword(
                {
                    minLength: 6, 
                    minLowercase: 1, 
                    minUppercase: 1, 
                    minSymbols: 1
                }).withMessage('Password is too weak. Field must contain min. of 6 characters, 1 lowercase and uppercase character and a symbol')
    ]
}

const validate = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        return next()
    }
    const extractedErrors = []
    errors.array().map(err => extractedErrors.push({ msg: err.msg }))

    // console.log(errors.array());

    res.status(200).json({
        statusCode: 400,
        errors: extractedErrors
    })
}

module.exports = {
    signupValidation,
    validate
}
```

Response on Postman

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "msg": "Invalid value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any help here would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-error-messages.html

What I did was to replace the code within the custom validation of the email body as show below

```
return MerchantTemp.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } }).then(user => {
                    if (user) {
                        return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
                    }
                });
```